# Unresolved reference: log

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I added  every gradle dependency which required for my project but I
am getting Unresolved reference: log issue when use log.info()
Here below my codes

> InventoryController.kt

```
package com.main.inventoryservice.controller

import com.main.inventoryservice.model.Inventory
import com.main.inventoryservice.repository.InventoryRepository
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*
import java.util.*


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/inventory")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
class InventoryController {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var inventoryRepository: InventoryRepository

@GetMapping("/{skuCode}")
fun isInStock(@PathVariable skuCode: String): Boolean? {
    log.info("Checking stock for product with skucode - $skuCode")
    val (_, _, stock) = inventoryRepository.findBySkuCode(skuCode)
        .orElseThrow { RuntimeException("Cannot Find Product by sku code $skuCode") }
    return stock!! > 0
}
}
```

I got error at this line

```
log.info("Checking stock for product with skucode - $skuCode")
unresolved refrence :log
```

> gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.20"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.20"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.5.20"
}

group = "com.main"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2020.0.3"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:5.4.6")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit:3.1.3")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp:3.0.2")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config")
    implementation("net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:6.6")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth")
    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I want to print some message through log ,so I Use log.info()but it is
not working and show error at log content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall use [`java.util.logging.Logger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html):

1. Importing:

   ```
   import java.util.logging.Logger;
   ```
2. Creating:

   ```
   class YourClass {
       private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLogger");
   }
   ```
3. Using:

   ```
   class YourClass {
       private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLogger");

       public void some() {
           logger.severe(":(");
           logger.warning(":|");
           logger.info(":)");
       }
   }
   ```